# How to bind multi Interpolation templates in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have `JSON` data that I want to display. I created a few functions to grab specific data from it (I couldn't find a better way).

I'm also trying to display them in order.

For example: The first function returning an array of the first items, the second function, the second items. I then want to display them in order. Firstly, I tried to do that directly from the JSON but I had a few issues because it may have nested in an array or object so I couldn't do it directly.

So, i'm trying to do something like this:

```
    <div class="head">
  <span class="text">
    {{ head.text }}
  </span>

  <span class="sub">
      {{ head.sub.value }}
    </span>

    <span class="text">
        {{ head.place }}
      </span>
</div>

<!-- for each body render the rest nested items... -->
<div class="body">  
  <span class="info">
    {{ body.id }}
    {{ body.info }}
  </span>
  <div class="extended">
    <span class="text">
      {{ extenden.spl.text }}
    </span>

    <span class="type.value">
        {{ extenden.spl.type.value }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the basic structure of the json:

```
[{
    "id": "XXX",
    "version": 1,
    "head": {
        "text": "Main title",
        "sub": {
            "value": "next"
        },
        "place": "secondary"
    },
    "body": [{
            "id": "XXX1",
            "info": "three little birds",
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "song",
                    "type": {
                        "value": "a"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "XXX2",
            "info": [
                "how are you?"
            ],
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "just",
                    "non-type": {
                        "value": "abc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

**And the most important thing!**

I know how to do that if I can assume the `JSON` properties!
My problem is I can't know if it's going to be an array or object or array of objects so

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items'>{{ item }}</div>
```

won't works for me!

Comment: Can't you use someting like `*ngFor="let user of result.users"` and then `{{user.firstName}}{{user.lastName}}`?

Comment: You should provide your functions code and maybe your `data$` model

Comment: Nope, since they different objects

Comment: Well can you share your objects structure then?

Comment: Yeah sure. Updated

Comment: I don't see any users property in your json ?

Comment: updated. I didn't expect to be misunderstood hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to try a different approach. you need to loop on a user object instead of the "properties of the user".

```
 <span class="headwordText" *ngFor="let user of users">
            {{ user.first }}, {{ user.last }}
  </span>
```

Comment: no, It won't work since sometimes the 'users' property is an object and and sometimes is an array

Comment: if it is an object, you can say it is an array with 1 object in it. so in your TS file try to make it so it will always return an array. alternatively, you can check if it is an object or an array inside your template (l ess recommended )

Comment: that's my main problem. I can't know if the json response wil be an objec or an array of objects..
and I can't find a way to do that properly.

I edited the post with the JSON structure

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but if I understood right this is the solution

In your ts file:

```
public fristnames : string[];
public lastnames : string[];

OnInit()
{
    firstnames = headwordFirst();
    lastnames =  headwordLast();
}
```

Now in your html file :

```
<div class="headwordDiv">
    <span class="headwordText" *ngFor="let firstname of firstnames ;let i = index">
        {{ firstname }} {{ lastnames[i] }}
    </span>
</div>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

```
<div *ngFor="let d of demo; let i = index">
  <span class="text">
     {{ d.head.text }}
  </span>
  <span class="sub">
      {{ d.head.sub.value }}
    </span>

    <span class="text">
        {{ d.head.place }}
      </span>
<ng-container *ngFor="let body of d.body">

  <span class="info">
    {{ body.id }}
    {{ body.info }}
  </span>
    <span class="text">
      {{ body.extended.spl.text }}
    </span>
    <span class="type.value">
        {{ body.extendend.spl.type.value }}
    </span>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, but as I said above I know how to render the data like this. The problem is, for example: {{ d.head.place }} the head property is an object or sometimes is an array.

Comment: use another ng-container to repeat the array